# Error message when installing new rails app ( error when installing byebug)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When launching a new rails app with the command "rails new movie_reviews", I get the following error message in my console:

"An error occurred while installing byebug (9.0.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '9.0.5'` succeeds before bundling."

This makes it impossible to install RUbygems such as "Devise" and others.

Do you know how to revolve the problem?

Comment: The full error stack will have more information about why `byebug` gem is not being installed. You could also move forward by removing `byebug` from the Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the gem, but had the following error stack:

"An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.11'` succeeds before bundling."

I couldn't find bcrypt in my gems, so couldn't remove it.

Comment: Best to include the full error stack from the `byebug` install in this question by editing it; that should help in figuring out the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use another debugger such as:

`gem 'pry'` and remove `gem 'byebug'`

Then run `bundle install`